# which combination(partiotioning ) has the smallest value?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

A positive integer can be partitioned, for example, the number 7 can be partitioned into the following:

$7=7$

$ 7=6+1$ , $ \ \ 7=5+2$,$ \ \ 7=4+3$

$ \ \ 7=4+2+1$,$ \ \ 7=3+3+1$,$ \ \ 7=3+2+2$,

$ \ \ 7=2+2+2+1$,...

I consider $n_k$ as the number of times that a number is used. For example, in partitioning $ 7 = 3 + 2 + 2$, we have $n_2 = 2$ and $ n_3 = 1$

suppose $K$ as largest element in every partiotioning , For example, in partitioning $ 7 = 3 + 2 + 2$ , $K$ is $3$ , and in the  partitioning $ 7 = 5 + 2 $ , we have $K=5$ .

let $\dbinom{1}{2}=0$ ,I want to know from all the above combinations Which one have smaller $P=\sum_{k=1}^K \dbinom{k}{2} n_k$ .(For example, in partitioning $ 7 = 3 + 2 + 2$  , this value is $P=\dbinom{3}{2} +2* \dbinom{2}{2} = 5  $)

I mean, which combination(partiotioning ) has the smallest value of $P=\sum_{k=2}^K \dbinom{k}{2} n_k$ ?

thanks

Comment: The partition that only uses ones (7=1+1+1+1+1+1+1) has value 0, right?

Comment: Hi @LinAlg we can't use 1, because the summation start from 2.

Comment: Ok, so a value of 0 cannot be attained. $2+1+1+\ldots+1$ has value 1.